# Data Migration between 2 table spaces

Tags: oracle

I need to migrate data from one a table store in table space (A) to a different table stored in table space (B).

Comment: where is the question ? you just mentioned what you have to do.

Comment: Is the target table empty? can you drop and re-create it? How big is the source table? Are both tablespaces in the same database? Do want to keep table `A` after you've migrated the data?

Comment: @APC No the target table is not empty. I want to append the table data from tablespace A to other table in tablespace B. Both the tablespace are in the same database. I cannot drop the old table after migration.

Answer (score 1):

Standard way of moving data is to use **Data Pump** - *export* from the source, *import* into the target.

This is 12c version's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A.htm#SUTIL2877, have a look.

Additionally, depending on database version you use, there are the *original* export/import utilities you might (have to) use.

---

[EDIT] Whoa? Two different "connections" became "tablespaces" (after you edited the question).

If it means that tables reside in the same database (but in different tablespaces), then a simple `insert` does the job, e.g.

```
insert into table_b select * from table_a
```

Tablespace isn't involved into that operation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before but i forgot that the table needs to have read access from other tablespace. My bad. And yes it works. :)